# ls filename does not work in lftp

Tags: unix, lftp

I created an lftp script to upload single files to a web hosting provider.

The use case is that I call it from the repository root, so the relative path is the same here and in the remote server.

```
#!/bin/bash

DIRNAME=$(dirname $1)
FILENAME=$(basename $1)
REPO_ROOT=$(pwd)
ABSOLUTE_PATH=${REPO_ROOT}/$1

lftp -u user,passwd -p port sftp://user@hosting <<EOF
cd $DIRNAME
put  $ABSOLUTE_PATH 
ls -l $FILENAME
quit 0
EOF
```

It works, with one small but annoying bug. To check that it really uploads the file, I have put an `ls -l` at the end. It fails and I do not understand why:

```
ls: Access failed: No such file(functions.php)
```

I tried to use `rels` and `cache flush` but in vain. I'm using lftp 4.0.9.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some googling at last gave a result in [mail-archive](http://www.mail-archive.com/lftp@uniyar.ac.ru/msg03087.html)

> It is a limitation of SFTP protocol implementation in lftp. It cannot
>   list a single file, only a specific directory.

Fortunately, lftp allows pipes, so

```
ls -l | grep  "$FILENAME"
```

solves the problem.