# lftp does not list files but allows download

Tags: sftp, lftp

I am writing a script to move files to and from an sftp server using lftp (version 3.7.3 running on an old FreeBSD server).

The problem is that lftp does not list existing **files** by executing ls and cls. It only lists directories.
I have tried mget * to fetch all files but that failed as well.
On the contrary cat and mget work perfectly if the filename is specified.
Clearing and then turning off the lftp cache did not make a difference.

I 've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16185575/ls-filename-does-not-work-in-lftp) link but it not my case. If I do "ls temp.txt" I get nothing instead of an error as in the link, although the file exists.

I can list the files using WinSCP and AnyFTP (an android app), so I guess it does not have anything to do with permissions.

Any ideas?

I managed to get this by adding a file named rc in ~/.lftp/ containing the word debug:

```
lftp myUserName@remoteHostIP:~> ls
---- Running connect program (ssh -a -x -s -l myUserName remoteHostIP sftp)
---> sending a packet, length=5, type=1(INIT), id=0
<--- myUserName@remoteHostIP's password: XXXX
<--- got a packet, length=5, type=2(VERSION), id=0
---- protocol version set to 3
---> sending a packet, length=10, type=16(REALPATH), id=1
<--- got a packet, length=47, type=104(NAME), id=1
---- home set to /myUserName/
---- path on wire is `/myUserName/'
---> sending a packet, length=22, type=11(OPENDIR), id=2
<--- got a packet, length=22, type=102(HANDLE), id=2
---- got file handle 4F70656E44697248616E646C65 (13)
---> sending a packet, length=22, type=12(READDIR), id=3
<--- got a packet, length=1238, type=104(NAME), id=3
---- file name count=11
---> sending a packet, length=22, type=12(READDIR), id=4
---> sending a packet, length=22, type=12(READDIR), id=5
<--- got a packet, length=28, type=101(STATUS), id=4
---- status code=1(EOF), message=End of file
---- eof
drw-rw-rw   1     root     root         0 Nov  6 20:03 test
drw-rw-rw   1     root     root         0 Nov  6 12:52 test1
---> sending a packet, length=22, type=4(CLOSE), id=6
<--- got a packet, length=28, type=101(STATUS), id=5
---- status code=1(EOF), message=End of file
<--- got a packet, length=24, type=101(STATUS), id=6
---- status code=0(OK), message=Success
lftp myUserName@remoteHostIP:~>
```

I also managed to list the files using java.

This is the WinSCP log file:

```
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.735 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.735 WinSCP Version 5.5.6 (Build 4746) (OS 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 - Windows 7 Professional)
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.735 Configuration: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Martin Prikryl\WinSCP 2\
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.735 Local account: mydomain\myWinUserName
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.735 Working directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.735 Process ID: 3116
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.735 Command-line: "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" 
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.736 Time zone: Current: GMT+2, Standard: GMT+2 (GTB Standard Time), DST: GMT+3 (GTB Daylight Time), DST Start: 26/3/2017, DST End: 29/10/2017
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.736 Login time: Τρίτη, 7 Νοέμβριος 2017 6:08:30 μμ
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.736 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.736 Session name: myUserName@remoteHostIP (Site)
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.736 Host name: remoteHostIP (Port: 22)
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.736 User name: myUserName (Password: Yes, Key file: No)
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.736 Tunnel: No
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.736 Transfer Protocol: SFTP
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.736 Ping type: -, Ping interval: 30 sec; Timeout: 15 sec
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.736 Proxy: none
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.736 Send buffer: 262144
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.736 SSH protocol version: 2; Compression: No
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.736 Bypass authentication: No
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.736 Try agent: Yes; Agent forwarding: No; TIS/CryptoCard: No; KI: Yes; GSSAPI: No
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.736 Ciphers: aes,blowfish,3des,WARN,arcfour,des; Ssh2DES: No
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.736 SSH Bugs: A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.736 Simple channel: Yes
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.736 Return code variable: Autodetect; Lookup user groups: A
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.736 Shell: default
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.736 EOL: 0, UTF: 2
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.736 Clear aliases: Yes, Unset nat.vars: Yes, Resolve symlinks: Yes
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.736 LS: ls -la, Ign LS warn: Yes, Scp1 Comp: No
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.736 Local directory: C:\Users\myComputerName.mydomain\Documents, Remote directory: /myUserName, Update: Yes, Cache: No
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.736 Cache directory changes: No, Permanent: Yes
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.736 DST mode: 1; Timezone offset: 0h 0m
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.736 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.846 Looking up host "remoteHostIP"
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.846 Connecting to remoteHostIP port 22
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.899 Server version: SSH-2.0-CoreFTP-0.3.3
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.899 Using SSH protocol version 2
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.899 We claim version: SSH-2.0-WinSCP_release_5.5.6
. 2017-11-07 18:08:30.911 Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
. 2017-11-07 18:08:31.159 Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-256
. 2017-11-07 18:08:32.181 Verifying host key rsa2 0x10001,0xcc1f532a43799760 7ff06787b19253a9 14e9acf3b711f594 1bd693efd365e88c 51281a973ecfd0c2 cfd758a92844a16e 704a0caa9fada7a0 235a4f2f00155466 a4fa7c6eabb16adc 89db04638e6904cf 8b50592da6072836 23c0517af0ccd732 d6d59d5f7665ab55 c20c428e702b94c9 18e9289271cdfe98 7972a59dd9ea48b9 79ccf8b13bbcc567 cac1952274a9d4db 689de1d09862f3a1 e88fb7576bd280c9 f50e4d6e72ec0e99 2fea70d254c87be5 b5505b5aa8ae90a9 71552671a65e32b7 a91d27b7eeac5922 6eb057c5a02bd8c7 4e54d87de9c13b55 d49291a3b8424e15 5eb8d90d4908f48e ba2ad7cf99af5d61 0b9530a426e70098 ac7454b39f66f07f  with fingerprint ssh-rsa 2048 76:a0:49:c8:6f:54:9a:8b:82:3b:19:d0:2a:c3:c7:e3
. 2017-11-07 18:08:32.206 Host key matches cached key
. 2017-11-07 18:08:32.206 Host key fingerprint is:
. 2017-11-07 18:08:32.206 ssh-rsa 2048 76:a0:49:c8:6f:54:9a:8b:82:3b:19:d0:2a:c3:c7:e3
. 2017-11-07 18:08:32.206 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
. 2017-11-07 18:08:32.206 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC algorithm
. 2017-11-07 18:08:32.214 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
. 2017-11-07 18:08:32.214 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC algorithm
! 2017-11-07 18:08:32.222 Using username "myUserName".
. 2017-11-07 18:08:32.269 Prompt (7, SSH password, , &Password: )
. 2017-11-07 18:08:32.269 Using stored password.
. 2017-11-07 18:08:32.316 Sent password
. 2017-11-07 18:08:32.327 Access granted
. 2017-11-07 18:08:32.327 Opening session as main channel
. 2017-11-07 18:08:32.336 Opened main channel
. 2017-11-07 18:08:32.557 Started a shell/command
. 2017-11-07 18:08:32.569 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2017-11-07 18:08:32.569 Using SFTP protocol.
. 2017-11-07 18:08:32.569 Doing startup conversation with host.
> 2017-11-07 18:08:32.621 Type: SSH_FXP_INIT, Size: 5, Number: -1
< 2017-11-07 18:08:32.834 Type: SSH_FXP_VERSION, Size: 5, Number: -1
. 2017-11-07 18:08:32.834 SFTP version 3 negotiated.
. 2017-11-07 18:08:32.834 We believe the server has signed timestamps bug
. 2017-11-07 18:08:32.834 We will use UTF-8 strings when appropriate
. 2017-11-07 18:08:32.873 Changing directory to "/myUserName".
. 2017-11-07 18:08:32.873 Getting real path for '/myUserName'
> 2017-11-07 18:08:32.873 Type: SSH_FXP_REALPATH, Size: 21, Number: 16
< 2017-11-07 18:08:32.882 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 47, Number: 16
. 2017-11-07 18:08:32.882 Real path is '/myUserName'
. 2017-11-07 18:08:32.882 Trying to open directory "/myUserName".
> 2017-11-07 18:08:32.882 Type: SSH_FXP_LSTAT, Size: 21, Number: 263
< 2017-11-07 18:08:32.892 Type: SSH_FXP_ATTRS, Size: 37, Number: 263
. 2017-11-07 18:08:32.892 Getting current directory name.
. 2017-11-07 18:08:33.023 Listing directory "/myUserName".
> 2017-11-07 18:08:33.023 Type: SSH_FXP_OPENDIR, Size: 21, Number: 523
< 2017-11-07 18:08:33.032 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 22, Number: 523
> 2017-11-07 18:08:33.032 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 22, Number: 780
< 2017-11-07 18:08:33.053 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 1238, Number: 780
> 2017-11-07 18:08:33.053 Type: SSH_FXP_READDIR, Size: 22, Number: 1036
< 2017-11-07 18:08:33.073 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 28, Number: 1036
< 2017-11-07 18:08:33.073 Status code: 1
> 2017-11-07 18:08:33.073 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 22, Number: 1284
. 2017-11-07 18:08:33.073 temp.txt;-;4;2017-11-06T10:58:10.000Z;"" [0];"" [0];rw-rw-rw-;1
. 2017-11-07 18:08:33.073 temp2222.txt;-;5;2017-11-06T18:09:34.000Z;"" [0];"" [0];rw-rw-rw-;1
. 2017-11-07 18:08:33.073 test;D;0;2017-11-06T18:03:00.000Z;"" [0];"" [0];rw-rw-rw-;1
. 2017-11-07 18:08:33.074 test1;D;0;2017-11-06T10:52:43.000Z;"" [0];"" [0];rw-rw-rw-;1
. 2017-11-07 18:08:33.074 test2.txt;-;8;2017-11-06T18:02:41.000Z;"" [0];"" [0];rw-rw-rw-;1
. 2017-11-07 18:08:33.074 test3.txt;-;8;2017-11-06T18:02:41.000Z;"" [0];"" [0];rw-rw-rw-;1
. 2017-11-07 18:08:33.074 test4.txt;-;8;2017-11-06T18:02:41.000Z;"" [0];"" [0];rw-rw-rw-;1
. 2017-11-07 18:08:33.074 test5.txt;-;8;2017-11-06T18:02:41.000Z;"" [0];"" [0];rw-rw-rw-;1
. 2017-11-07 18:08:33.074 test6.txt;-;8;2017-11-06T18:02:41.000Z;"" [0];"" [0];rw-rw-rw-;1
. 2017-11-07 18:08:33.074 test7.txt;-;8;2017-11-06T18:02:41.000Z;"" [0];"" [0];rw-rw-rw-;1
. 2017-11-07 18:08:33.074 test8.txt;-;8;2017-11-06T18:02:41.000Z;"" [0];"" [0];rw-rw-rw-;1
. 2017-11-07 18:08:33.173 Startup conversation with host finished.
. 2017-11-07 18:08:34.064 Not refreshing directory, caching is off.
```

Comment: Show us lftp and WinSCP log files.

Comment: And WinSCP log file?

Comment: What do you do before the `ls`? Show us your script.

Comment: I am currently testing without any script, so I just login with :
` /usr/local/bin/lftp "sftp://myUserName:password@remoteHostIP"   `

Comment: And you start in `/myUserName/` straight away?

Comment: Did you try the same against some more standard SFTP server (=OpenSSH, even the local one)?